# If $(Df)(x_*)$ has a striclty positive eigenvalue then $x_*$ is instable for $\dot x = f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples, stability-in-odes

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable, let $\dot x = f(x)$ be an autonomous ODE, and let $x_* \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a critical point.

**Question:** I want to show or find a counterexample to the claim that if $(Df)(x_*)$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $\text{Re}(\lambda) > 0$, then the point $x_*$ is not stable.

For $n = 1$ this is true, but I am not sure about higher dimensions.

My motivation for this question is the following:
If $\dot x = f(x) = Ax$ was a linear system with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ then the claim were true. For real eigenvalues this can be seen as follows: Bring $A$ into Jordan normal form, $A = V J V^{-1}$. The solutions to the linear ODE are of the form $e^{At} x_0 = V e^{tJ} V^{-1} x_0$. Then pick some eigenvector $v$ to an eigenvalue with strictly positive real part as the initial value. Then we have

$$ e^{At} v = V e^{tJ} V^{-1} v = V (0, \ldots, 0, e^{\lambda t}, 0, \ldots, 0)^T = e^{t \lambda} v$$

Since $\lambda > 0$, we have $\Vert x(t) \Vert \rightarrow \infty$ for $t \rightarrow \infty$. Since we may choose the start value, which was an eigenvector to $\lambda$ with arbitrarily small norm, this shows instability.

For complex eigenvalues this ought to be not much different, except for some rotational terms.

---

We know that if all the eigenvalues have strictly negative real part, then $x_*$ is stable (even exponentially, asymptotically stable). This uses the same result for the linear case, and then applies this to the Taylor expansion of $f$. However, for this to work, one needs a modified version that takes into account the higher order Taylor rest. This is done using Gronwoll's Lemma.
Also, if the largest real part of the eigenvalues is $0$, anything can happen; even in dimension $1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann My again - fixed. Thanks

Comment: You get a strong claim in the [Hartman-Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem) that directly addresses your question. There is no such counter example.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Great. Thank you very much once again!